# Would this photodiode sensor work better in series or parallel?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current-source, infrared, photodiode

I am working on a photodiode small object sensor that detects and records signatures of objects passing through an array of photodiodes facing an array of IR LEDs. I am connecting the photodiodes to the two channels of the Max86141, but would like to use more than two photodiodes per channel to cover a large area.

Would this work better with photodiodes in series or in parallel? How would the signal differ between the two options?

Comment: Unless you need the precision, you might consider quad op-amps as 4 transimpedance amplifiers. Based on your text all photo-diodes must prove the objects presence at the same time. You need simple logic to verify if all photo-diodes are in an ON or OFF state.

Comment: As per @csabahu answer, they must work in parallel, each with its own transimpedance converter.

Comment: Instead of using multiple diodes per channel, is using a lens to image a larger area onto a smaller photodiode an option?

Answer (score 1):

There is no point connecting the photodiodes in series, as they are all current sources. Two or more current sources may not be (as appropriate) connected in series. The lowest current will be decisive.
When connected in parallel, the currents add up and both operate independently. In the case of several diodes connected to one input, only the parallel connection makes sense.

[image: bpw]

Comment: Is there much of an issue with the lowest current being decisive though? Or would this give the first photodiode in the series more "weight" than the other ones? For example, if photodiodes A, B, C were connected in series in order, A being shaded would have a larger effect on current output than C being shaded?

Comment: @chris v When the two diodes are connected in [series](https://imgur.com/a/uc6PzJ1), the dark appears to be dominant. The better lit, as if it weren't even there. So the current is always determined by the darkest (lowest current) of the diodes connected in series.

Comment: So we don’t sense anything about the change with the better lit diode.

Comment: right, so if i have LEDs one one side and photodiodes on the other, and an object passes one series photodiode, there would be a large response as if they were all triggered. Doesnt that work for object detection?

Comment: Actually, yes, but the answer will only be as if you were using a single diode. This is similar to the phenomenon of shadow passing through a series with previous solar cells. Despite the others being illuminated, this series did not provide energy.
There will be a change (the same amount) with parallel connecting, but the others still work, so it is well known that something obscured one, or e.g. three diodes.

Comment: I even find it problematic that the diodes should not be placed away from the Maxim chip. Neither in series nor in parallel. The diodes must be physically at the input of the transimpedance amplifier. The LEDs can be placed further away.

Comment: So parallel could provide a better picture of object size, while series could give a more stark signal disturbance? 


Also, its important that the photodiodes are not physically next to the Maxim? In my current set up it they are a few cm of distance away from the Max86141 (on the same PCB), and I am seeing a decent response in parallel.

Comment: Then it's so fair. I thought the diodes were further away and that wouldn't be good.
Another problem with the series connecting would be that if something accidentally obscures one, none of it will work.

Answer (score 1):

To perform exactly what signatures you want from only 2 channels  with multiple sensors, you must define the object size, stray light source and PD occluded beamwidth with gaps and LED beamwidth as these play a role.

I have done similar to detect an object as small as a wire or a case of beer in the bottom of the basket (BOB) of a shopping cart in a 1m isle . By sequencing 7 LEDs in a signature array , I could also detect the nose of the cart and any object in BOB by sequencing unique binary coded pulses of light at 100kbps rates to each LED so that 7 matched aligned PD’s with AGC amplifiers inside could be uniquely blocked.  To get the laser like resolution , the pulse emitter beam  and detector  beam were shaped by recessing in wood to restrict the wide beam into a very narrow one.. I could also measure velocity and direction of the object moving.

Your geometry and resolution will be different and still is TBD for functional signature to use multiple angular beams into 2 Rx channels for a 2D signature . But you may also want to measure velocity if the object speed is not constant.

I did not use simple PDs an TIA’s rather std SMD IR data receivers with my custom protocol in a continuous loop using a PIC uC on the Rx side and 100mA pulse to 5mm LEDs on the Tx side with same sequential word per LED in a fast loop.

Comment: Wow that sounds exactly like what I want to achieve. So the object would cross  perpendicular to the array of LEDs? Have you made this design public? I would love to check it out!